# compare 2 observable array with different structures and mark matching row selected

Tags: knockout.js

Lets say i have below 2 observable array

```
var data1 = [{
name1: "one",
id: 1,
IsSelected: false
  }, 
{
name1: "two",
id: 2,
IsSelected: false
 }, 
{
name1: "three",
id: 3,
IsSelected: false
}];

var data2 = [{
 name2: "five"
 }, 
 {
 name2: "two"
 }, 
 {
 name2: "three"
}];
```

From 2 arrays you can see 2 rows are matching "two" and "three". Those matching rows are binded to checkbox and marked as checked.

Now what i want is if rows are matching then it should set IsSelected property to true if rows are matching.

I am aware that flattening array will make structure same of 2 array. But what i want is to  compare 2 arrays and mark IsSelected property to true if data matches.

This is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jq3ru/84/) to reduce your confusion if any.

I have really ran out of ideas to achieve this. In fiddle you can see that 2 boxes are checked but it shows false beside it. It should show as true.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer can you help me on this please?

Answer (score 1):

May be [this](http://jsfiddle.net/damienobringer/Jq3ru/103/) will be helpful

```
self.isDuplicated = function (item) {
    var data2 = viewModel.dataTwo();
    for (var index = 0; index < data2.length; index++) {
        if (data2[index].name == item.name) return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: will you modify my fiddle?

Comment: No, I make a new one based on yours.

Comment: @Damein i need IsSelected property. You have removed in your fiddle. Please update my fiddle keeping IsSelected property. Many thanks

Comment: As you asked, I add the isSelected property

Comment: i will get back to you on this. Didnt understood why you moved IsSelected property from data1 to Data1. Cant you keep it where it was before?

Comment: Because isSelected is a ko.computed, so it's evalute as soon as you declare it.
In this sample, isSelected refers to viewModel, but viewModel doesn't exist yet.
If you don't create the Data1 class, you will have to copy the isSelected code to each item of data1 array.

By the way I think it's better to separate raw data (data1) from computed Object (Data1).
So you can easily add computed properties.

Comment: just help on one more thing then. With your example how will i make IsSelected true or false on checkbox checked event. The reason i added IsSelected was because when i will send data to server then each row in data1 obs array will have IsSelected true or false. Then in my wcf service i will consider only IsSelected = true rows. Hope you got my point. Ultimately i will send json object of data1 to service

Comment: OK, I didn't understand right (my fault).
I update the jsFiddle.

Comment: but now checkbox are not checked.

Comment: Yes, an item can be selected or dupilicated or both. duplicated means that data2 contains an item with the same name selected means the checkbox is checked. You said : "With your example how will i make IsSelected true or false on checkbox checked event". So duplicated isn't linked to selected.

Comment: So when an item is checked it will be copied into data2

Comment: data1 and data2 are compared. The data matching between 2 will be used to check the box. The IsSelected property will be either true or false depending upon checkbox is checked or not. data1 will ultimately be send to server. Then my service will only select those rows which has IsSelected as true. Hope you have enough explaination. Dont at all hesitate to ask if any doubt. I am upvoting the answer as you have supported me a lot. Still solution is not completed.

Comment: The checkbox is bind to isSelected property and has no "link" to the duplicate state. But the value of checkbox is initialized accordingly to the duplicate state of item.

Comment: seems ok but can we avoid using viewModel.checksDuplicated(). Why we need it? Is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: checksDuplicated aims to select duplicated items like two and three.

Comment: but can we avoid it that call

Comment: If you don't call it, the duplicated items won't be selected by default.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for late reply. I am using another approach to bind my checkbox. I have now merged 2 tables in one and now its quite easy for me to check and uncheck and see what has changed